# What happens when $\frac{d^{2}f}{dxdy}\geq 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Here's my question:

Let $f:R^{2} \to R$ be twice differentiable. Show that $\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x\partial y}\geq 0$ iff for every real $x, x', y, y'$:

$x>x'$ and $y>y'$ implies that $f(x,y)-f(x,y')\geq f(x',y)- f(x',y')$.

It has been a while since I've taken multivariable calculus, so I'm not really sure where to start. I don't know what information I can deduce if I assume $\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y}\geq 0$, for example. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess there's some information missing. like $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\ge0$ for all $x$ and $y$ iff ...

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: You're going to want to use the single-variable mean value theorem twice. Consider $g(y)=f(x,y)-f(x',y)$. You want to show that $g(y)-g(y')\ge 0$. What does the mean value theorem tell you about $g(y)-g(y')$? Recall that $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$.